# Compute differences between all variable pairs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidy, pairwise-distance

I have a dataframe with 4 columns.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = round(rnorm(1000, mean = 1)),
           B = rpois(1000, lambda = 3),
           C = round(rnorm(1000, mean = -1)),
           D = round(rnorm(1000, mean = 0)))
```

I would like to compute the differences for every possible combination of my columns (A-B, A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D, C-D) at every row of my dataframe.
This would be the equivalent of doing `df$A - df$B` for every combination.

Can we use the `dist()` function to compute this efficiently as I have a very large dataset? I would like to then convert the dist object into a `data.frame` to plot the results with `ggplot2`.
**Unless there is a good `tidy` version of doing the above.**

Many Thanks

The closest I got was doing the below, but I am not sure to what the column names refer to.

```
d <- apply(as.matrix(df), 1, function(e) as.vector(dist(e)))
t(d)
```

Comment: `dist` will compare every value in A to every other value in A, so if you are looking to compare columns row-by-row, this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: How are these distances? DO you mean differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base r:

```r
df_dist <- t(apply(df, 1, dist))
colnames(df_dist) <- apply(combn(names(df), 2), 2, paste0, collapse = "_")
```

If you really want to use a tidy-approach, you could go with `c_across`, but this also removes the names, and is much slower if your data is huge

Comment: Thanks, interestingly this gives the same results as @Allan Cameron but as absolute differences instead.

Answer (score 2):

`dist` will compare every value in a vector to every other value in the same vector, so if you are looking to compare columns row-by-row, this is not what you are looking for.

If you just want to calculate the difference between all columns pairwise, you can do:

```r
df <- cbind(df, 
            do.call(cbind, lapply(asplit(combn(names(df), 2), 2), function(x) {
  setNames(data.frame(df[x[1]] - df[x[2]]), paste(x, collapse = ""))
})))

head(df)
#>   A B  C  D AB AC AD BC BD CD
#> 1 0 1 -2 -1 -1  2  1  3  2 -1
#> 2 1 1 -1  1  0  2  0  2  0 -2
#> 3 3 1 -2 -1  2  5  4  3  2 -1
#> 4 1 3  0 -1 -2  1  2  3  4  1
#> 5 1 3  0  1 -2  1  0  3  2 -1
#> 6 3 3  1  0  0  2  3  2  3  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate on why dist is not appropriate? @Jonathan managed to get the same results (in absolute values however) as you using dist.